# Writing proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let a be a rational number and b an irrational number. Prove:

a ≠ 0 → ab is irrational

Proof by contradiction:

1.Suppose not, if a ≠ 0 , then ab is rational

2. Let a be any rational number and b be any irrational number (from the question)

   2.1 Then a = c/d, for some integer c and d, d ≠ 0 (by definition of rational number)

   2.2 Since a ≠ 0, then c/d ≠ 0

   2.3 Since c/d ≠ 0 , c ≠ 0 ( by basic algebra)

   2.4 ab = e/f , for some integer e and f, f ≠ 0 (by definition of rational number)

   2.5 c/d * (b) = e/f ( by substitution)

   ```
          b = (e*d) / (f*c) (by basic algebra)

          b = (ed)/(fc)
   ```

   2.6 ed is an integer ( by closure of multiplication)

   2.7 Similarly, fc is an integer (by closure of multiplication)

   2.8 fc ≠ 0 (since f ≠0 , c≠0)

   2.9 Hence, b is a rational number ( fraction of two integers, denominator is nonzero)

3 But this leads to contradiction, where b is an irrational number.

4 Therefore the assumption that ab is rational is false.

Hence,if a≠ 0, then ab is irrational.

My question is: is it alright that I assume that ab is rational in the first place and show how it leads to a contradiction and therefore proved the original statement to be true?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is

If $a$ is non-zero rational and $b$ is irrational, then $ab$ is irrational.

The negation of this, which gives contradiction is

$a$ is non-zero rational and $b$ is irrational AND $ab$ is rational.

It is basically what you've written, but with more rigor.

The remaining part of proof is correct and, it, as it should, leads you to a contradiction that $ab$ is the same time rational and irrational (which is absurd). This is the idea of assuming that $ab$ is rational.

Comment: I think  you have misunderstood my proof. My proof is that b is the same time rational and irrational, so it leads to a contradiction and therefore the original statement is correct.

Comment: I think my made a mistake, it is wrong to write if a ≠ 0, then ab is rational( it means a=0 OR ab is rational) The negation should be a≠0 AND ab is rational, am I right?

Comment: The negation of A -> B is (A ^ ~B) (^ stands for AND and ~ stands for negation). Your proof is correct in general, I just fixed a negation, in point 1 of your proof

Comment: The general idea of proof by contradiction is that given statement to be proved, you negate it and show that it results in a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now, rmb to change the first part of my proof, I dont want to mislead anyone seeing my post.